# Rails selecting record that has particular records through has_many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I've set up a messaging system between characters as follows. Each character `has_many :conversations` with other characters `through: :chat_groups`. Fairly standard setup I expect.

character.rb

```
has_many :chat_groups, class_name: "Chat",
                       foreign_key: "character_id",
                       dependent: :destroy

has_many :conversations, through: :chat_groups, source: :conversation

has_many :messages, as: :messageable
```

conversation.rb

```
has_many :chat_participants, class_name: "Chat",
                             foreign_key: "conversation_id",
                             dependent: :destroy

has_many :characters, through: :chat_participants, source: :character

has_many :messages, as: :messageable
```

chat.rb

```
belongs_to :character
belongs_to :conversation
```

message.rb

```
belongs_to :messageable, polymorphic: true
```

When a character (`@sender`) sends a message to another character (`@recipient`), I first need to check if a conversation between ONLY the two characters already exists, and if not, to create such a conversation. A conversation involving the two characters and other characters (a group chat) may already exist, and this should be rejected.
Something like `Conversation.has(@sender).and_has(@recipient).and(has_no_more_characters)`.

My question is, what's the best/most efficient way to query for the existence of such a conversation?